# UITableView - how to dynamically update frame of self-resizing cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I successfully implemented the self-resizing cells with autolayout. I added a UITextField to my content view that takes a string from the model, and the cell is now resizing correctly according to the length of the string.

The user is supposed to be able to edit this text field - how do I update the frame of the cell on user input (as the text field grows)?

I could resize the cells and the rest of the table view manually, but I figured there might be a better and simpler way to invalidate and refresh the frame of the cell that is being edited?

I want the frame changes to animate smoothly (e.g. as the textfield text requires a new line, this cell grows in height, and the cells below are pushed down accordingly).[image: editing uitextview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to refresh a single cell you can do the following:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Obviously you should change the indexpath to the correct one for your cell.

If you do this in something like `textViewDidBeginEditing` after checking if the `contentSize` of the `UITextView` has changed you should get the effect you're after.